# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar todas las comillas simples ( ' ) al inicio y al final de cada valor en un DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo el siguiente DataFrame:

[image: datos con comillas simples al inicio y al final]

Todas la variables tiene unas comillas simples, y quisiera eliminarlas.

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué intentaste? Quizás te sirva leer [ask] como guía.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con:

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.replace('\'','')
```

Donde `df` es tu data frame.

Comment: Hola, al ejecutarlo el DataFrame sigue quedando con las comillas.

Comment: Uhm. ¿Con qué estás visualizando los datos? ¿Será posible que las comillas son un indicador del visualizador para indicar que son strings?